# Use Find Method to look for the of a Range from another worksheet

Tags: excel

I am currently stuck in the Find method not properly working in my current project.  The idea is there are 2 sheets.  VBA should copy the range value from worksheet "Seed" and then go to another sheet ("Source") and find the same value in "Source" sheet.

Cells.Find(Worksheets("SEED").application.ActiveCell.Value, xlValues, xlByColumns).Activate

Comment: "to look for the <what>? of a Range"??? Have you considered splitting up the different activities into different steps of code? i.e. copy a range, then perform a find, instead of doing it all in one line of code? And why "Activate"? That is one of the most useless statements ever

Comment: Teylyn,  it's like the statement gets the value of a range in worksheet seed say the value of the range is "apple", the code then transfers from sheet "seed" to sheet "source" and looks for apple in that sheet performs certain action then goes back to sheet seed and gets another range value to find in sheet source... this will continue to loop.

do you have any suggestion? appreciate all the help.  thanks

Comment: No, "it's like" I read your subject line and there are words missing and "it's like" it does not make sense. Please get your act together before your question gets closed and use proper language to help people understand what you "like" want to say.